# ftp file retrieve for unfinished file

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

What is the best way for a program which retrieves files from ftp server to check if the file to be downloaded is an ongoing transfer (someone already uploading this file during we decide to download). Do ftp client apis handle this ? (e.g. apache commons ftp client).

Answer (score 1):

i think it's not really possible. a couple years ago i had a similar problem and i've got 2 options. (unfortunatelly it was C#, not Java)
you can check if the file's still growing (implies that you're gonna have a small delay because you need to check twice) or if you're using windows (i don't know how linux works) you can try to access this file and you should get an exception that the file is in use by another process.
just two possibilities and a starter for you to think about your problem. maybe someone else'
s coming up with a really good solution, but for now that might be a little workaround for you

Answer (score 1):

Ftp was not designed to tell you if a file is in use, the most the ftp daemon can do is deny the transfer, and that is configurable in some servers. There may be a server that renames files temporarily or offer a script to do so , but you'd have to find one.

Answer (score 1):

Do not know if it is sufficient for you, but if you need only some "dum" check, I would try `System.getSecurityManager().checkDelete()`. File can be deleted only if no streams are opened.